# Attempting to circumvent pysvn, can I use the subprocess function to write svn calls in shell script?

Tags: python, bash, svn, subprocess

I'm having some trouble understanding the subprocess function in Python 2.7.  I have some commands in shell script that I'm trying to convert into Python, `svn export -r 5 ...` for example, but I don't want to depend on a library such as `pysvn` to do this.  The solution to that (to my understanding) is to use a subprocess and just run each individual command that would be in a shell script.  Should this be achieved by `subprocess.call("svn export -r 5", shell=True)`?  Or is `Popen` what I should be looking at?  I know that it's been said you should avoid `shell=True`, but there is no security concern or possible user error in my case.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `pysvn`. Use SWIG Python bindings: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.developer.usingapi.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs

Comment: I am trying to avoid downloading any libraries, which is why I am using a subprocess, but it is still helpful to make a note of SWIG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call` is just a thin wrapper around `subprocess.Popen` that waits for the process to complete:

```
def call(*args, **kwargs):
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
```

The only reason to use the shell to run your command is if you want to run some more or less complicated shell command. With a single simple command and its arguments, it is better to pass a single list of strings consisting of the command name and its arguments.

```
subprocess.call(["svn", "export", "-r", "5"])
```

If you were writing a function that could, for example, take a revision number as an argument, you can pass that to `svn export` as long as you ensure that it is a string:

```
def svn_export(r):
    subprocess.call(["svn", "export", "-r", str(r)])
```